# ¿Como crear un ArrayList de meses?

Tags: java, android, array, date

Buenas mi consulta es la siguiente. Quisiera armar un arreglo de meses con el mes actual mas 3 ó 6 meses anteriores. Hasta ahora logré obtener el mes actual pero no tengo mucha idea de como obtener los meses anteriores e ir creando un array con esos valores.

```
ArrayList<String> prevMonths = new ArrayList<>();

DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
Date dateMonth = new Date();
String currentMonth = dateFormat.format(dateMonth));
Log.e("Mes", currentMonth);
```

Sé que debo crear un ArrayList y con un bucle for tratar de ir llenandolo con los valores correspondientes pero no encuentro la forma correcta:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
    //cuando el count llega a 6 se detiene el bucle
    //Agregar currentMonth + los meses anteriores al arreglo prevMonths
    prevMonths.add()...
}
```

Mi problema es que no se como iterar para que la funcion vaya agregando los meses, podrían darme una ayuda con esto? Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso se puede resolver usando `Calendar` esa clase tiene método para agregar intervalos de tiempo.

```
ArrayList<String> prevMonths = new ArrayList<>();

DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");

// establecer los meses anteriores que se desean agregar
int mesesAnteriores = 6;

for (int i = 0; i <= mesesAnteriores; i++) {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    // se resta un mes a la fecha actual
    // empezando en 0 que sería el mes actual
    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -i);

    Date dateMonth = calendar.getTime();

    String currentMonth = dateFormat.format(dateMonth);

    prevMonths.add(currentMonth);
}
```

Comment: Hola @Lobos gracias por tu respuesta! Tengo una consulta, es correcto que se salteen algunos meses? Hice unas pruebas con tu respuesta y al hacer un log de los valores me devuelve esto: [Oct, Sep, Jul, Apr, Dec, Jul, Jun]. O debo implementar algo mas para que los meses anteriores sean correctos?

Comment: Sí, había un error. Ya actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: Entiendo, había que hacerlo dentro de la iteracion. Gracias!